# How to implement a default view in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP each method of a Controller has its own View and the view template file is the name of the method.

```php
class DataController extends AppController 
{
  public function one()
  {
    // will render one.ctp
  }

  public function two()
  {
    // will render two.ctp
  }
}
```

Accourding to the API documentation there is a [`$view`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#144-150) property of the Controller that specifies the view to render. So I should have the ability to specify a default view file, say `all.ctp`, for all methods of a controller

```php
class DataController extends AppController 
{
  public $view = 'all';

  public function one()
  {
    // should render all.ctp
  }

  public function two()
  {
    // should render all.ctp
  }
}
```

However this does not work and CakePHP ignores the `$view` property and continues to look for the template file of the same name as the method.

Is there a way to have a default view without having to insert `$this->render('all');` in each of the Controller's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is going to be overridden in [`Controller::setRequest()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#454) which is being called in the controllers class [constructor](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#336).

You could use your controllers [`beforeFilter()` callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3abeforeFilter) instead to set the value:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->view = 'all';
}
```